# AspectJ hello world, need some advise

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

I need some help about AspectJ and maven. I wrote simple application with `AspectJ`'s aspects.

`src/main/java` - default package

```
public class Main 
{
    public int a = 10; 
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Main instance = new Main();
        System.out.println(instance.test());
    }

    public int test(){
        return a;
    }
}
```

and

`src/main/aspects` - default-package

```
public aspect TestAspect {
    pointcut publicMethodExecuted(): execution(public !static * *(..));

    int around() : publicMethodExecuted() {    
         int original_return_value = proceed();
         return original_return_value * 100;
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>group.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>
                                    <basedir>src/main/aspects</basedir>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/TestAspect.aj</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

***I. Command-line way***

Now I do the following:

```
mvn install
java -jar test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and I got the output `10`. But I expected it to be `1000`.

***II. Eclipse AJDT way***

If I run that proejct from within `Eclipse AJDT` I got `1000` as I expected.

What's worng with command-line way?

When I run `mvn install -X`

I found a line

```
[WARNING] advice defined in TestAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
        D:\aspectJ\aspectj-lib\src\main\aspect\TestAspect.aj:4
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: maybe try `mvn package` instead of `mvn install`

Comment: @NendoTaka Have tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure all of the files are being included properly?

Comment: @NendoTaka What do you mean included properly?

Comment: Are the above function in different or the same file?

Comment: @NendoTaka I don't unserstand how it can affect on the result ever. Eclipse AJDT executes the application in the way I expected it to.

Comment: I am wondering if all of the files/directories were actually found by mvn. Sometimes you have to add a directory as a resource under build. For example https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

Comment: @NendoTaka Yes, In the Jar-file I have both ` TestAspect.class` and `Main.class` classes

Comment: Could you confirm based on the Maven output of the aspectj-maven-plugin the Main.class is indeed touched and changed. Maybe you need to add -X to the commandline arguments to see more details.

Comment: @RobertScholte I found the line `[INFO] No modifications found skipping aspectJ compile`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: the default aspect directory is `src/main/aspect` - you may want to check your configuration (and if `aspects` is neccessary)

Answer (score 1):

> [INFO] No modifications found skipping aspectJ compile

Yes. that explains it. This is normally done by comparing dates of files, e.g. the source files and the class files. This is probably caused by your IDE. There's a flag for the plugin called [forceAjcCompile](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#forceAjcCompile), however, I see that the plugin writers forgot to expose it for the commandline. Simple (not best) solutions are: add `<forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>` to the configuration of the plugin, or run `mvn clean package`.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration seems flawed

try this instead:

```
        <configuration>
          <aspectDirectory>src/main/aspects</aspectDirectory>
        </configuration>
```

you could omit this completely, if you used the default `src/main/aspect` directory.